# How to get multiple values at once using MPI_GET?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I'm working with MPI OneSided Communication and I have somes
issues. Here is my code and, to help you understand, here goes a brief
description.

```
void evolve_network(u_int32_t *neighborhood, u_int8_t *lattice,
                    u_int32_t *network,  u_int8_t *rule,
                    int rank, u_int32_t amount_cell_proc,
                    MPI_Win win)
{
    u_int32_t i, j, index_rule;
    u_int8_t *temp = malloc (11 * sizeof(u_int8_t));
    u_int32_t offset, proc;

    for(i = 0; i < amount_cell_proc; i++){

        get_index_neighborhood(neighborhood, network, i, 10);

        MPI_Win_fence((MPI_MODE_NOPUT|MPI_MODE_NOPRECEDE), win);

        for (j = 0; j < 11; j++){

            proc   = get_process(neighborhood[j], amount_cell_proc);
            offset = get_shift(neighborhood[j], amount_cell_proc, rank);

            MPI_Get(&temp[j], 1, MPI_UINT8_T, proc, offset, 1, MPI_UINT8_T, win);
        }

        MPI_Win_fence(MPI_MODE_NOSUCCEED, win);

        index_rule = BinaryToDecimal(temp, 10);
        lattice[i] = rule[index_rule];
    }
}
```

The first loop goes through the cells that each process has and for
each cell it gets its neighborhood. The neighborhood is a sequence of
indexes returned by `get_index_neighborhood` and stored in the
neighborhood array. Then, inside the second loop, for each index in
the neighborhood array, I get which process that index belongs to and which
is the offset using the functions `get_process` and `get_shift`
repectively. Both values are used in MPI_GET function.

The function to `evolve_network` is called n times in the program
exectuion and for each time I'm calculating the proc and offset
again. I want to improve it calculating these values once and storing
them in a structure called `map`. So, in the other calls of
`evolve_network` function I read these values from `map` struture avoiding
unnecessary calculations. This way each process will have an array with the indexes that it needs to get.

My question is: Is there anyway of getting the offsets all at once? So that, the MPI_GET function would return the values stored in a window indicated by theses indexes.

I'm not sure if I was clear enough and apologize for my poor English.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please edit your question and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). it should contain the loop of `MPI_Get()` that you would like to be optimized in a single call.

Comment: you can `MPI_Get()` several values from a **single** proc in one shot using a MPI derived datatype. But as far as i am concerned, you cannot `MPI_Get()` from **many** procs in one shot (no such thing as one sided collective).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Is exactly what I want, get several values from a single process in one shot. In my searches, I found out the MPI_Type_Indexed and I guess that it will help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: note that `proc` is not a loop invariant, so your code might try to `MPI_Get()` from several MPI tasks. be sure you understand the difference between `MPI_Type_indexed()` and `MPI_Type_create_hindexed()` so you use the one that is good for your needs. if you need to retrieve data with several datatypes, then `MPI_Type_Create_Struct()` is what you need.